# scalajs-react: Idiomatic way of processing ajax response

Tags: reactjs, scala, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am sending a GET request to backend rest service, as follows:

```
def showAllEmployees =  Callback {
    org.scalajs.dom.ext.Ajax.get(url = "http://localhost:8081/fetchAllEmployees").onComplete {
      case Success(xhr) => {
        Callback.log(xhr.responseText)
      }
      case Failure(t) => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

I want to extract the records from the response. I observe that code inside case Success is not even executed.

So what is idiomatic way of doing it in scalajs-react?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use [scalajs-react Ajax](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/EXTRA.md#ajax). It already returns `Callback`.

Comment: I tried that too. I see no change in behaviour. Code inside onComplete is never called.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are wrapping your ajax call into `Callback`, it means in order to ex ecute it - you have to call `.runNow()`
2. In case of `Success` response you are doing  `Callback.log(xhr.responseText)` which is `Callback` that needs to evaluated again, but as you are inside `onComplete` which returns `Unit` - it is not possible to do. So, ether do `Callback.log(xhr.responseText).runNow()` or just use `println`

Working example:

```
def showAllEmployees =
  Callback {
    org.scalajs.dom.ext.Ajax
      .get(url =
        "https://run.mocky.io/v3/53993bf9-c589-4886-956b-e0b35a1ab13e"
      )
      .onComplete {
        case Success(xhr) =>
          Callback.log(xhr.responseText).runNow()
        case Failure(t) => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
      }
  }
```